# string in javascript are immutable, but when we use let with strings , it becomes changeable,

Tags: javascript, string, constants, mutable, let

string in JavaScript are immutable, but when we use 'let' with strings , it becomes changeable, which tends to mean that they are mutable, how can we justify that strings are immutable yet it is mutable when use with let?

Comment: You're changing the variable, not the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me help you with that using an example.

Consider we declare a string using let

```js
let someString = 'This is a String'
```

now you can **Re-assign** that variable `someString` to a new value which means `let` variables can be reassigned.

```js
someString = 'Some new Value'
```

But `Strings` are immutable in the sense that you can't mutate the ***content*** of the String.

```js
someString[1] = 'A' //This is Invalid since Strings are Immuatable
```

Happy Coding :)